# iOS Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found

Tags: ios, xcode6

After updating to Xcode 6, I am unable to build my project. I am trying to use it for testing on an iPad with iOS 8 but when I hit "Build" I get the following error:

> Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier, com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers.
>   CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.0'

Comment: Check my answer here: tp://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567481/xcode-makes-invalid-distribution-profiles-on-member-center/25569735#25569735

Comment: After adding that new App ID I was able to copy it and paste it into the bundle ID under the project settings in Xcode. This fixed it. Thanks!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Ill be glad also if you vote up my answer!

Answer (score 0):

I followed Erid's answer which led me to creating a new App ID in the Apple Dev Center. I then copied that App ID over to Xcode under Bundle ID and replaced the one I had there with the one I just created. Now I can build the project.

Comment: My App ID was still in use by the App Store so I could not re-create it, instead I switched off iCloud usage in it and switched on again, of course I had to regenerate all the provisioning profiles also, that helped me.